# Local transport to Warsaw airport

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, warsaw, waw

I'm going to take the **local train S3** from *Warsaw Central rail station* to *Chopin airport*.

I have some question on the ticket procedure. According to Internet, the trip takes ca 20min.

1. Is a normal 20min ticket enough, from the machines?
2. I read that I have to validate the ticket.

   2.1 Is it possible to do this inside train?

   2.2 If not, after validating the ticket outside the train, I think 20min is not enough anymore, since I validate it before train arrives.

   2.3 So, how to procedure?

Answer (score 2):

The validators outside trains are only on metro. S3 is a city train, and the validators are inside the trains.

However, if the trip takes longer for any reason (for example, many passangers getting in/out has delayed the departure), it is still your responsibility to travel on valid ticket.

Comment: So, to be legal, I should have a ticket for zone 1 and also the duration of trip can not be 27min, even inside zone 1?

Comment: Because in some schedule, the same origin/destination takes more time, more than 20min.